# Questions regarding wormy source code?

Tags: python, pygame

so I recently started looking into GUIs and I'm looking at a source code for the game wormy which can be found: [here](https://inventwithpython.com/wormy.py). I just have a few questions regarding this source code.

What does the sys module do in this code? I know that the sys module provides information about constants, functions and methods of the Python interpreter (taken from a website), but in this source code the only thing that the sys module is actually doing is being imported and then terminated when the game is closed? So I'm a bit confused about that.

In addition, I am wondering on how I can change the squares to look like circles instead? I tried changing the module functions (Rect and draw.rect) to draw.circle but an error keeps popping up. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `sys.exit()` makes your python code exit ... and as to the other I would strongly recommend reading the documentation

Comment: I'm aware of that, sorry I didn't clarify, but can someone tell me if the sys is really necessary in the entire code itself?

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question - you've asked more than one question, and your debugging question provides neither the code nor the error.

Comment: Pygame.quit() will exit the game and sys.exit() will end the script and free up your systems resources.

Answer (score 0):

When using pygame.draw.circle(), it will take different arguments than rect(). Look at the documentation [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle). Post your code and your error message for better help.